# Probability textbooks repository

Tags: textbooks, probability

(This question was [posted more than two years ago](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90349/probability-textbooks) on math.stackexchange.com and, although there were some worthwhile answers, none actually answered the question as phrased.)

Has anyone compiled a moderately comprehensive list on the web or elsewhere of textbooks on probability

- For students who have not been introduced to the subject before
- That introduce both discrete and continuous probability distributions and their cumulative distribution functions, and include things like
  the Poisson limit theorem, the central limit theorem (say the former
  with proof and the latter not necessarily), and
- That perhaps cover the simplest stochastic processes like the Poisson process or
  infinite sequences of Bernoulli trials?

Experience using these texts and a short description of how it went would also be welcome.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want all three of these properties within each recommended book? (as opposed to three lists of recommended texts)

Comment: I added the "probability" tag, and included a sentence at the end that will hopefully enrich the kinds of answers you get.

Comment: I had in mind all in each book.

Comment: Perhaps http://www.cargalmathbooks.com/#Probability will help a little.

Comment: @JW : Maybe you should make your comment a posted answer.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Thanks for the suggestion. I thought that a single link wasn't substantial enough for an answer, so I posted it as a comment.

Comment: One can also refer to https://g.co/kgs/fj1ZEq to understand the concepts of probability and other statistics topics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps: http://collegeopentextbooks.org/opentextbookcontent/open-textbooks-by-subject/statisticsandprobability

or as JW suggested:
http://www.cargalmathbooks.com/#Probability

Beyond these list, I have not yet found one.